# git diff showing differences following git reset

Tags: git

There are a couple of binary files in my git repo that refuse to consider themselves unchanged. This is a Windows env so the first thing i do is check autocrlf:

```
> git config core.autocrlf
false
```

Now i reset to get rid of any changes:

```
> git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 6d67f13
```

Now i check for differences:

```
> git diff
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
diff --git a/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot b/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
index 33b2bb8..ec6fb3a 100644
Binary files a/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot and b/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot differ
diff --git a/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 b/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
index 3311d58..680a9dd 100644
Binary files a/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 and b/resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 differ
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in resources/public/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

My understanding is that with autocrlf set to false the warnings above shouldn't be happening. Also, these are both binary files, and so such replacements shouldn't be happening regardless. What am i missing?

Comment: Setting `core.autocrlf` to `false` just means that Git doesn't *assume* every file is text. It still applies crlf translations to files that it is *told* are text. It seems likely that you have a `.gitattributes` file that forces text interpretation for these two binary files (for non-diff purposes; for diff purposes they're still being treated as binary).

Comment: Yeah, .gitattributes has this line: "* text eol=lf". It's proven tricky to reproduce the problem, but playing with that line has for now gotten rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @torek for the hint. The problem appears to have been the .gitattributes file in the project that had this line:

```
* text eol=lf
```

Taking out the "text" bit seems to have solved the problem.